# Comment in RPG?

Tags: rpgle, rpg

I would like to put in comment several lines. In the documentation, we can use this -> `(/*...*/)`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzajp/rzajpcommentsirpg.htm

I tried several times but it does not work.

```
/*
   dsply 'Enter your number1 please : ' '' Number1;
   dsply 'Enter your number2 please : ' '' Number2;
*/
```

I am obliged to use two slashs on each line.

```
//dsply 'Enter your number1 please : ' '' Number1;
//dsply 'Enter your number2 please : ' '' Number2;
```

I don't like. Do have you an idea please?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That only applies to embedded SQL, not regular RPG... from the manual:

> Bracketed comments (/*...*/) are allowed within embedded SQL statements whenever a blank is allowed

Comment: [RPG Reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzasd/coment.htm)  for comments outside of an embedded SQL Statement

Answer (score 0):

You could use /IF and /ENDIF to remove several lines from the compile:

```
/IF DEFINED(skip)
   dsply 'Enter your number1 please : ' '' Number1;
   dsply 'Enter your number2 please : ' '' Number2;
/ENDIF
```

If you actually want to use that code sometimes, use some more meaningful condition that you can define with the DEFINE parameter on the CRTBNDRPG or CRTRPGMOD command or with the /DEFINE directive.

```
/IF DEFINED(prompt_for_input)
   dsply 'Enter your number1 please : ' '' Number1;
   dsply 'Enter your number2 please : ' '' Number2;
/ENDIF
```

Comment: or you can write a If (1 = 2); <your code>; EndIf;